# assigned a value to characters and perform a mathematical functions (+,-,*,/) of a string (having characters) in MS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, ms-office-script

I want to perform a sum of a given string ('ABCDEF') based on its pre-assigned values.
i.e first I want to assign values to each character and then calculate the total value of the string having pre-assigned characters. Is it possible to carryout this function in excel? eg. is below

```
A=2, B=5, C=8, D=1, E=1, F=2
sum of 'ABCDE'=17
sum of 'FAC'=12
```

Comment: It is certainly possible, but what attempt have you taken from your end. could you show us that? And why did you use `ms-office-script` tag?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I have been working on hit and trial method. I have been trying hard to find on internet and tried all the suggested possible options but hard luck. Its hard to mention all of them in the question.
I think it could be a part of 'ms-office-script' so I have tagged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is what I have ***tried***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **E1** --> **Applicable to Excel 2021 & O365 Users Only**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(LEN(D1)),1),$A$1:$B$6,2,0))
```

• Formula used in cell **F1** --> **Applicable to All Users**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D1))),1),$A$1:$B$6,2,0))
```

Depending on Excel Version may or may need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` for the above formula!

The above formula(s) works well when used for one **`Mathematical`** Operator, however if you want to use **Multiple Operator**, then I assume Defining Named Ranges for each of those characters and then use them for **`Mathematical`** functions, shall be an easy one!

Comment: Thanks... This is exactly what I am looking for but somehow it doesn't work for me. I am exactly mimicking your formula but it shows #NAME? error.

Comment: @shivam what is your Excel Version? are you using **O365**?

Comment: I am using "Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64-bit"

Comment: @shivam Check now, the 2nd Formula should work, the earlier one was for **Excel 2021** & **O365** Users

Comment: Thanks @Mayukh your updated  formula '(=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D1))),1),$A$1:$B$6,2,0)))' works perfectly in LibreOffice Sheet but doesn't work in MS Excel. 
Not sure what is the problem with the MS excel. It always show '2' as answer

Comment: @shivam there should not be any issue in Excel as well, you may need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

Comment: Thanks Bhai, I tried ctrl+shift+enter but hard luck :(

Comment: @shivam wait I am sharing, I understood, why it happened, could you share me a `One-Drive` link in the comments

Comment: Please find the link 
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ambh7Xh1BFhYau9l01HS8u1_ysc?e=CvT1eH

Comment: Seems some problem is with my excel. in one drive it works perfectly but as I download it and open in excel it automatically converts to "2"